# How to solve "failed to get device after detach: failed to wait for detach replug: device did not come back" when fwupdmgr update to upgrade firmware?

Tags: debian, upgrade, firmware

I was trying to upgrade the firmware with `fwupdmgr update` but I'm getting this output on Debian11/KDE:

```
Unifying Receiver and all connected devices may not be usable while updating. Continue with update? [Y|n]: Y
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
failed to get device after detach: failed to wait for detach replug: device {id} did not come back
```

How to solve this to upgrade the Unifying Receiver firmware?

---

Edit 1:

I already tried plugging it out and reconnecting it during upgrade (and if this is needed the user should prompted to do so in the console) but it only changed the output: instead of the error message line it displayed "not supported". I also installed `solaar` but there's no button in that app to upgrade the firmware.

---

Edit 2:

This is very strange, now it could install an update even though I already changed IP earlier and nothing changed then. I'd like to know how this can occur. I'm still having this problem because it only did one update but not a second update. I'm having the same problem with the second update.

When I ran this command which worked at first try there was `• System Firmware` under `Devices with no available firmware updates:` which previously wasn't there. And it's not there when I tried updating again.

The output of the first try command that worked is:

```
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • [...]
 • [...]
 • [...]
 • System Firmware
 • [...]
Upgrade available for Unifying Receiver from RQR[...] to RQR[...]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Updating Unifying Receiver…**************************************]
Writing…                 [***************************************]
Successfully installed firmware
Upgrade available for Unifying Receiver from RQR[...] to RQR[...]
Unifying Receiver and all connected devices may not be usable while updating. Continue with update? [Y|n]: Y
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
failed to get device after detach: failed to wait for detach replug: device {id} did not come back
```

---

Edit 3:

Maybe it was partly caused by having two Unifying Receivers. I also tried disconnecting each and rerunning the command. Because solaar wasn't needed and I wasn't prompted to install it, I didn't have it installed before I tried these updates. Using it I now configured the receivers so that I only need one of them. After doing so I reran the update command and now I got this as last line instead of the failed to get device error: `Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying`. When running it again I now get this:

```
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • [...]
 • [...]
 • [...]
 • System Firmware
 • [...]
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Unifying Receiver
```

I guess it's the latest version now?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

- install `solaar`
- disconnect one of the receivers
- by using an USB-connected keyboard (and the tab button or a USB-connected mouse) pair all the devices you previously had connected with the receiver
- rerun the command a few times

This only worked for one of the two Unifying Receivers I had connected, but I haven't tried long with the other receiver.

Edit: this wasn't the solution, the same error reappears after a restart so the firmware wasn't upgraded successfully despite it displaying the latest version. I get the same error again and had to run the command a few times until it prompted me for the root password. I couldn't install it so far (on both of the USB receivers).
I created a bug report **[here](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/4259)** and will update this answer if a solution is found there.